# Partitioned table - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created this table  :

```
CREATE TABLE operation_tache_person (
    id_tache INT,
    id_person INT ,
    operations varchar(10),
    CONSTRAINT operation_taches_cle_primaire primary key(id_tache,id_person)  ,
    CONSTRAINT operation_taches_tache_cle_etrange FOREIGN KEY(id_tache) REFERENCES taches(id_tache) ,
    CONSTRAINT operation_taches_person_cle_etrange  
    FOREIGN KEY(id_person) REFERENCES person(id_person)  
)
```

the `operations` attribute can take one of 3 values : `c`, `d` OR `u`

I want to know if I partitioning this table on `operations` will increase performance, if yes is it necessary to make "operations" as primary key to partition it? And could you show me how can I partition it.

And thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paritioning is a design decision and can't be decided just looking a table structure.

But still if your column takes just 3 values then paritioning is not the solution because all of your data will be kept in just 3 partitions which means that you will still be dealing with huge data even after partitioning. So that will be wrong choice .

Comment: uh ok ... thank you ... i guess ya i m not partitioning  this table :)